# Accessing local data from an offline web application

Tags: html, database, cross-platform, local, offline

I would like to write an html/javascript/sql app for personal use only running locally (not for downloading over the internet) which would interact with a large local database (about 3MB) and display images and text drawn from a very large pool of resources stored locally (about 2GB).

I already have such an app written in Java for Android, but am interested in re-developing it so that it would be capable of being run on different platforms (iOS, etc),if possible.

My immediate question is: is it possible for an "offline web application" to access a pre-existing locally stored database and to read locally stored resources? Information that I have found so far on the web talks about cached data which doesn't sound like the same thing.

Comment: The original version of my app is an ".hta" running in Internet Explorer where the data (accessed via Microsoft TDC) and the resources are stored in sub-folders of the folder containing the .hta file. Essentially, what I am looking to do is to create something similar that will run in browsers other than IE, including those on mobile phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can simply develop a HTML file that will run locally on your device (be it a PC, mobile, or whatever).

You could then take advantage of the HTML5 WebDatabases for your database needs - this should work in any modern browser and runs client-side.

Regarding your photos, I would store them in a subfolder of your HTML file. This way, you can show them within your webbrowser using regular image tags like:

```
<img alt="" src="file://path/to/your/images/images1.jpg" />
```

To pre-populate, or transition, from a SQLite database you can take a look at this sample code: https://github.com/atkinson/phonegap-prepopulate-db

It utilizes a dump of the SQLite database and the FileReader of HTML5 to iterate over the data and insert it into the browser-based WebDatabases or Web SQL database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By Webdatabases do you mean those that are cached by the browser? How would I get the data in? Or could I point the browser at an existing database?

Comment: What format is your existing database?
If your database is compatible with the syntax of SQLite, then you could look into using Web SQL: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/
Be aware though that it has been deprecated in favor of WebDatabases (that to my knowledge, are not compatible with any existing database).

Comment: The data is currently in an SQLite database, but I would hopefully be able to convert it to an alternative format. However, "Web Databases are hosted and persisted inside a user's browser" ... My question remains:  how do I get the large bulk of data in? With my Android app I can copy the SQLite database onto the SD card via USB. If I had a web server I could presumably add code to my html app to read data into a database cached by the browser. But I don't have a web server.

Comment: I edited my answer to fill in details on how to populate the database based on your existing SQLite.

Comment: Thanks very much. That's very helpful. If I understand correctly this code imports the contents of an SQL dump file (stored in a subfolder of the folder where the app is) into a Web Database. Would I expect to import the data just once and subsequently rely on the cached database being complete? Or would it be advisable to reimport the data each time the app is run?

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt help.